# Import Outlook calendar events into Google calendar as an RSS feed?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rss, google-calendar

I am starting a new job soon. My company uses Outlook for our work calendars. While I was in college, my significant other and I used a shared Google Calendar to keep track of where we were since we dated long distance. Now that I am starting my job, I would like to automatically import my work calendar events into my shared Google calendar.

I know that I have calendars (RSS Feed style) that live update and I'd like to do the same thing here. When a new event gets added or subtracted from my Outlook calendar, I would like this change to be reflected on my shared Google calendar. Is it possible at all to do something like this?

I know that there may be limitations based upon our IT security.  However, I'm just trying to understand now so I can see how to do this once work starts (versus manually updating the calendar). Even if there was a way just to get the time (shown as busy) that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook 2013:

Right click on Calendar > Share > Share Calendar. If you have Office 365, then it should take you to OWA and you have to set the calendar permissions. You should be able to Add by Url the .ICS link. This is read-only. I'm not sure how often Google grabs the new calendar file, but you can refresh it manually if you need to: https://www.binarysludge.com/2012/02/01/how-to-force-refresh-google-calendar/